# How do I protect my customized code from being overridden by theme updates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to WordPress but I'm eagerly learning my way around. I'm currently working on my company's website and we purchased a theme from [Gorilla Themes](http://gorillathemes.com/). While customizing some of the features that came with the theme, I have thus far modified the following files:

1. /functions/meta-boxes-code.php
2. /functions/menu-and-settings-page.php
3. /includes/find-cars.php

They suggested that I do this in a Child theme and with their help I was able to setup a child theme, create a style.css file with an import statement to the parent style.css file, and activate it.

However, I'm concerned now that should the parent theme get updated all the customization I've made in the files above will be lost. I've already tried copying the **/functions** and **/includes** folders into my child theme folder (being careful to maintain the directory structure), but that didn't work - WordPress simply ignored it and loaded from the parent.

So my question is, how do I use the functionality of the customized files from my child theme?

**PS.  I have also sought assistance from the [WordPress support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-use-customized-code-from-parent-theme-in-my-child-theme?replies=1), just waiting for someone to reply to my thread.**

Comment: It's not true for all premium theme templates, but many will add a theme settings link in the WP admin where you can add customized content/styles/etc., and since it is stored in the database itself it won't be broken on theme updates. Again, might not be the case here, but something to look for.

Comment: Try creating `functions.php` within your child theme folder i.e. `/child-theme-folder/functions.php`- you can add all of your customisations in that file. It will be loaded in addition to the parent theme's functions.php file so you'll retain that functionality whilst still being able to add your own.

Comment: @GreatBlakes my theme's vendor didn't provide a way to customize it from the admin backend.  Henry, I tried the approach you suggested, but that didn't work.  It appears not all the functions in the parent are wrapped in if( function_exists (&#039;function_name&#039;)) statements.